# Is there any concept like RDS(Remote Data Services) in .net?

Tags: ado.net, ado, rds

Is there any concept like RDS(Remote Data Services)  in .net ???

Answer (score 1):

WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)
.Net Remoting
ASP.NET Ajax.

Those are your options and any one of them is a light year ahead of RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASP.NET AJAX and script services:

http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax/tutorial-05-cs.aspx

Javascript in the browser calling web services on the server is probably the closest thing to RDS. The web services don't necessarily have to be XML web services, you could use JSON as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is VB6's RDS.DataSpace.  In .NET, you can use either WebServices(http-based, more analogous to RDS), or Remoting(tcpip-based, more analogous to DCOM, sans the multiple opening of ports).